# Can't open search results in Bing in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, bing

I upgraded Windows 7 to Windows 8 yesterday. When I use Bing on the Windows 8 start menu to search for something, I can't open the results in an browser. When I click the tags on the results page, nothing happens. Why?

In the first result on the picture below, when I click it, it just turns gray. I think there should be a browser pop up bringing me to the target page, but nothing happens.

[image]

How can I get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following suggestions:

- Try a different app (like Mail) and check if links open a browser.
- Install Chrome and set it as default browser.
- Unset and re-set IE as the default browser.
- Uninstall and reinstall Bing.

Comment: Thanks for the remainder, it works after I refresh my machine. the step to do this is, Settings - PC settings - General - Refresh your PC without affecting your files.